# HOW TO : High traffic db

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling

Though this can be very abstract question, please show me any proper direction.

DB design and replication configurations for Twitter-like webapp (heavy inserts & reads).

Comment: Hey man, I can promise you people will answer you well if you do the following: show us what you have already, if you have nothing show us what you *think* you should have, describe the project in much greater detail. People on S.O. seem to get grumpy if you don't give enough detail, especially if your question is so abstract that it sounds like "Do my job for me."  I can promise you that if you start with what I told you (the details) people will tease out the rest of your question.

Answer (score 1):

For a very high loads, you might consider [NoSQL databases](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). This solution works well, when you mostly need to read data, and your data logic is not to complex. NoSQL solutions can be times faster then relational databases, when properly configured.

If you want to go with MySQL, this question is too abstract. There are tons of things you need to think about:

1. proper table structure
2. proper indexing
3. caching
4. normalization and denormalization
5. your queries
6. clustering

Google all of these, to understand why those questions are important. If you are serious about getting the best out of MySQL performance, I really recommend "[High performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718)" - this book is terrific.

[image: High performance MySQL]

Comment: As far as I understand NoSQL is no faster than SQL when ACID qualities are enforced. When you drop any of ACID in your application, SQL solution will perform as fast as NoSQL.

Comment: @Victor: SQL databases will (almost) always be a bit heavier since they are general purpose, while a special purpose dbms should be a bit faster.  And NoSQL isn't a product. It's a term that refers to dbms that differs from relational databases in some way. This article does a pretty good job at matching hammers with nails: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html